# kernel programming: No rule to make target `−C'

Tags: makefile, kernel

I am trying to learn kernel programming but while trying to compile a simple hello world program i am getting the following error.

> make −C /lib/modules/3.2.0-67-generic/build M=/home/arun/KPrograms modules
>   make[1]: Entering directory `/home/arun/KPrograms'
>   make[1]: *** No rule to make target`−C'.  Stop.
>   make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/arun/KPrograms'
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

my **Makefile** is

```
obj−m += hello−1.o

all:
    make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should replace all the `−C` in Makefile into `-C`. The dash character is incorrect.

Comment: Did printk vomit out the output on your console ? In my case it didnt, i had to check /var/log/kern.log file

Answer (score 2):

**Hi all,**

You must type your code on your own. In some cases copy paste does not work. You must enter it like this:

```
obj-m............<enter>

all:....<enter>

<tab>make -C.............<enter>

clean:..............<enter>

<tab>make -C...........<esc> <:wq>
```

That will probably solve your problem.
good luck